# Domain controller is registering 2 IP addresses with DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller, a-record

Recently a DC was promoted and the IP was used from the old DC which was demoted and shutdown.How tostop this DC from registering 2 IP addresses with DNS? Please let me know if any questions.

Comment: If the server only has one IP now, delete the incorrect entry in DNS, does it come back?

Comment: Yeah. Does not look like it registers as much as you have leftover garbage in teh DNS and expected the DC to magically clean it up (which it will not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the IP addresses on the same NIC, or seperate NICs?  If separate, then you in the connection properties, you can tell it not to register itself with DNS.  If the same, then if it's Win2008 or higher, you can use netsh like this: `Netsh Int IPv4 Add Address <Interface Name> <IP Address> SkipAsSource=True` http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2012/02/08/fine-grained-control-when-registering-multiple-ips.aspx.  Otherwise, you'd have to turn off auto registration in DNS and manually create the single entry you want.